# Logical operator outside parentheses

Tags: matlab, if-statement, operator-keyword

I can't figure out what the logical operator "not" (`~`/`!`), does in front of a parenthesis.

Here is the task:

I have `a = 1`, `b = 2` and `c = 2`.

and this `if` statement:

`if (a ~= b | a ~= c) &&`**~**`(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c)`

What does it mean having a logical operator "not" before the parenthesis (look at the bold `~`)?

Comment: it means "not true what is in parenthesis". to satisfy this if `(a ~= b | a ~= c)` should return true and `(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c)` should return false

Answer (score 3):

It plays the role of a logic-negation. It'll return the logical negation of `(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c)`. Meaning if `(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c)` is true, then `~(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c)` is false. and vice versa.

`not(A)` is equivalent to `~A`. The symbol `~` acts like the `not(A)` logical operator if `A` is a logical expression. The same symbol `~` placed before `=` acts like the `ne(A)` relational operator.

Matlab employs short-circuiting behavior when dealing with logical operators `&&` and `||`. Meaning that if we are evaluating e.g `expr1 && expr2`, then `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `0` (`false`). Same way happens when we evaluate e.g `expr1 || expr2`, `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `1` (`true`).

The symbols `|` and `||` perform different operations in a MATLAB application. The symbol `|` is an element-wise OR operator. The short-circuit OR operator is `||`. meaning that if we have e.g `expr1 || expr2`, both `expr1` and `expr2` are evaluated. Same thing happens with the `&` element-wise AND operator.

Now, let's have a look at the expression you asked for:

```
if (a ~= b | a ~= c) &&~(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c)
```

Knowing that: `a = 1`, `b = 2` and `c = 2`.

```
expr1 = (a ~= b | a ~= c) 
      = (1 ~= 2 | 1 ~= 2) 
      = 1 (true)
```

expr1 is true, so Matlab proceeds to evaluate expr2:

```
expr2 = ~(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c) 
      = ~(1 ~= 2 && a ~= c && b ~= c) 
      = ~(1 && 1 ~= 2 && b ~= c) 
      = ~(1 && 1 && 2 ~= 2) 
      = ~(1 && 1 && 0) 
      = ~(0) 
      = 1 (true)
```

So the final result of `expr1 && expr2` is `1` (`true`).

Hope it's useful!

Comment: In this case (a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c) is false. Then will this:
~(a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c) be true in this case?

Comment: @Basil: Yes. But, please, see my updated answer for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to complement the Academia's answer - the evaluation order is important and every logical operator has it's precedence. In Matlab the negation operator '~' not() has higher precedence than other logical operators. In this case the expression `a ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c` will be evaluated before the negation operator as a whole because it was placed inside the parenthesis. This expression can be read as "all three variables have different values". By placing it inside the parenthesis and negating it, you get "not all three variables have different values". Without the parenthesis you'd get `not(a) ~= b && a ~= c && b ~= c`. Note also that comparison operators have higher precedence than &&.

Hope it helps.